# How to get location where my links clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, hyperlink

for exam I have a site : mysites1.com
and I have an url of my site like this

```
mysites.com/hellowolrd.
```

When others put some content like this on mysite2.com

```
Hello this is my site <a href='http://mysites.com/hellowolrd'>
```

How can I know this link clicked from othersite.com?
Are there any api or service help that?
Thank so much

Answer (score 2):

use `HTTP_REFERER` in php `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` to get referer site ,please see here for complete usage

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-http-referer-variable/

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
document.referrer;
```

It will give you url from where current page has been redirected.

You have to write Javascript code on http ://mysites.com/hellowolrd page:

```
if(document.referrer=="mysite2.com")
{
    alert("Url redirected from mysite2.com");
}
else
{
    alert("Url redirected from other page.");
}
```

Hope it will work.